# Optimizing if statements using loops in Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to optimize the large amount of if statements present in this code:

```
public class MyClass{
    ArrayList<Stack<String>> positions = new ArrayList<Stack<String>>();

    Stack<String> pos1;
    Stack<String> pos2;
    Stack<String> pos3;
    Stack<String> pos4;
    Stack<String> pos5;
    Stack<String> pos6;
    Stack<String> pos7;
    Stack<String> pos8;
    Stack<String> pos9;
    Stack<String> pos10;
    Stack<String> pos11;
    Stack<String> pos12;
    Stack<String> pos13;
    Stack<String> pos14;
    Stack<String> pos15;
    Stack<String> pos16;
    Stack<String> pos17;
    Stack<String> pos18;
    Stack<String> pos19;
    Stack<String> pos20;
    Stack<String> pos21;
    Stack<String> pos22;
    Stack<String> pos23;
    Stack<String> pos24;
    Stack<String> pos25;
    Stack<String> pos26;
    Stack<String> pos27;

public ClassName{
        for (int i=0; i<28; i++) {
            positions.add(i,new Stack<String>());
        }


}

public void Updater (int position, boolean player){


        if(player){ // if player one is up
            // start position 1 actions
            if(position==1){
                int distance = pos1.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ // only make move if player one's chip is on top of the stack
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos2.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos3.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos7.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos8.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos9.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==9){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==10){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==11){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==12){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==13){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance>13){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    pos1.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 1 actions

            // start position 2 actions
            if(position==2){
                int distance = pos2.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos3.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos7.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos8.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos9.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==9){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==10){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==11){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos2.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance>11){
                    String temp = pos2.peek();
                    pos2.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 2 actions

            // start position 3 actions
            if(position==3){
                int distance = pos3.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos7.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos8.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos9.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==9){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==10){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==11){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos3.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance>11){
                    String temp = pos3.peek();
                    pos3.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 3 actions

            // start position 7 actions
            if(position==7){
                int distance = pos7.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos8.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos9.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==9){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==10){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos7.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance>10){
                    String temp = pos7.peek();
                    pos7.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 7 actions

            // start position 8 actions
            if(position==8){
                int distance = pos8.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos9.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==9){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos8.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance>9){
                    String temp = pos8.peek();
                    pos8.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 8 actions

            // start position 9 actions
            if(position==9){
                int distance = pos9.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos9.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance>8){
                    String temp = pos9.peek();
                    pos9.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 9 actions

            // start position 10 actions
            if(position==10){
                int distance = pos10.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos10.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                   
                if(distance>7){
                    String temp = pos10.peek();
                    pos10.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 10 actions

            // start position 11 actions
            if(position==11){
                int distance = pos11.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos11.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos11.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos11.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos11.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos11.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos11.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                   
                if(distance>6){
                    String temp = pos11.peek();
                    pos11.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 11 actions

            // start position 12 actions
            if(position==12){
                int distance = pos12.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos12.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos12.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos12.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos12.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos12.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos12.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos12.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos12.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }           
                if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos12.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos12.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                               
                if(distance>5){
                    String temp = pos12.peek();
                    pos12.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 12 actions

            // start position 13 actions
            if(position==13){
                int distance = pos13.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos13.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos13.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos13.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos13.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos13.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos13.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos13.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos13.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                                       
                if(distance>4){
                    String temp = pos13.peek();
                    pos13.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 13 actions

            // start position 14 actions
            if(position==14){
                int distance = pos14.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos14.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos14.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos14.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos14.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }               
                if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos14.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){ 
                        pos14.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                                                   
                if(distance>3){
                    String temp = pos14.peek();
                    pos14.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 14 actions

            // start position 15 actions
            if(position==15){
                int distance = pos15.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos15.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos15.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos15.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos15.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                                           
                if(distance>2){
                    String temp = pos15.peek();
                    pos15.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 15 actions

            // start position 16 actions
            if(position==15){
                int distance = pos16.size();    
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos16.peek();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos16.pop();
                        pos17.push(temp);
                    }
                }                                   
                if(distance>1){
                    String temp = pos16.peek();
                    pos16.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 16 actions

            // start position 17 actions
            if(position==17){
                int distance = pos17.size();                                    
                if(distance>=1){
                    String temp = pos17.peek();
                    pos17.pop();
                    if(temp=="x"){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 17 actions

            player = false;
            frame.player.setText("Current Player's Turn: Player Two");
        }
}
```

}

Basically, there are 25 stacks which each store various strings of x's and o's. The updater method moves the x's and o's from one stack to another, based on parameters. Is it really necessary to write as many if statements as I did here to cover each scenario? Is there a loop that I could use instead?

The x's and o's can only be moved forward, not backwards.

Comment: Looks like an awful, brittle design to me.

Comment: My eyes... The goggles...

Comment: The design is poor but you can do it with arrays and maps.

Comment: If you use the arraylist "positions" instead of separated fields, then you can calculate the source stack and target stack, thus reducing the ifs.

Comment: try switch case where there is more data than usual, but still you need to work on the design too.

Comment: am i mistaking or are you reading `distance` one time and checking it lots of times with subsequent `if`s, why not use `else if(...)` ???

Comment: `temp == "x"` should be `temp.equals("x")`

Comment: @Luciano this is what I'm looking to do. I know how to target the source and target indexes that contain the stacks that I need to push/pop/peek on. However, I'm not sure how to actually call a method on those stacks from there.

Comment: @Bob something like positions.get(position).pop(); positions.get(position + distance + ??).push(...)

Comment: Does a switch statement not at least speed up the process if not cleaning the code up at all?

Comment: A switch statement isn't what is necessary. The design is off. The author needs to find a function which computes the next position from a given position. That way, he won't need all the cases, he will just have a function to apply to a given position.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't create an array of stacks? Then you could reduce if statements with:

```
Stack[] stacks = new Stack[27];
Arrays.fill(stacks, new Stack<String>);
if (temp.equals("x")) {
   Stack stack = stacks[distance];
   //all other stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the design problem very effectively. He needs a function to calculate the next move from a given move. Currently, there is no function, so he hardcodes the next move from a current move, which requires the branching.

Answer (score 1):

the statement : `if(distance==1){`
can be replaced by something like this :

```
for(int i= 0 ;i< 13;i++) {
        if(distance==i) {
            // some code
            break; // break the loop once match is found
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method is just as inefficient as the method above because you are hitting all of the if statements. You should throw a break in then yours will be awesome.

Comment: yes you are correct. I totally agree. Will edit the post. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize you can start by using `else if` in 90% of your reoccuring if statments. That way you only hit the one you need and not all of them. This will reduce bugginess also.

```
if(player){ // if player one is up
            // start position 1 actions
            if(position==1){
                int distance = pos1.size(); 
                if(distance==1){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){ // only make move if player one's chip is on top of the stack
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos2.push(temp);
                    }
                }
               else if(distance==2){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos3.push(temp);
                    }
                }
               else if(distance==3){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos7.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==4){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos8.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==5){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos9.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==6){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos10.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==7){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos11.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==8){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos12.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==9){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos13.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==10){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos14.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==11){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos15.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==12){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance==13){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos1.pop();
                        pos16.push(temp);
                    }
                }
                else if(distance>13){
                    String temp = pos1.peek();
                    pos1.pop();
                    if(temp.equals("x")){
                        pos26.push(temp); // push to player one's winners circle
                    }
                }

            }
            // end position 1 actions
```

Comment: Always put { } brackets to have maintainable code. "else" AND "if" are two separate keywords....remember? Java doesn't have "elseif"

Comment: Will using else if prevent unnecessary code from being executed, once an if statement matches the conditions?

Comment: @Bob Yes it will stop checking the rest

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see what strings you were refering to now. I just coppied OP's code and added the else if in to show him. You are correct. He should be using temp.equals("#")

Comment: "else if" my eyes! what if you put log statement in else? it will break down your "else if" pyramid....e.g. "else LOG.debug("..."); if"

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested `for` loops and then `if` test based on the value of `i`:

```
for(int i = 1;i<=15;i++)//position
{
for(int c = 1;c<=4;c++)//distance
{
if(position==i)//etc.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to do:

If you find yourself doing a lot if `if(distance==1){` ... `pos1.pop();` then `if(distance==2){` ... `pos2.pop();` etc., the use the `ArrayList<Stack<String>>` you already declared, and just get the one you need.

```
if (/* distance is within bounds */)
{
    Stack<String> pos = positions.get(distance);
    ...
```

You can do something similar with the `temp` value you get back to determine which one you need to push to.  This will eliminate all those duplicated-code `if` blocks.

Next, in each case you compare string values with the `==` operator.  The `==` operator compares references to see if they are the same, which is probably not what you want here.  Use `String#equals` to compare `String` values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips.

Create the stacks dynamically:

```
int total = 27
List<Stack<String>> positions = new ArrayList<Stack<String>>();
for (i = 0; i < toal; i++){
   positions.add(new Stack<String>());
}
```

You can now access them with `positions.get(position);`

You can greatly simplify the code:

```
Stack<String> positionStack = positions.get(position);
int distance = positionStack.size();
if (positionStack.peek().equals("x")){
   positions(nextMove(position).push(positionStack.pop());
}
```

`nextMove(int position)` is a function that calculates the next position from a given position. I do not know what that function is, but you can come up with it.